# Search for string in object (the object contains many other objects as well)

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the following code, after calling `Catalog.scan(1, 100)`, `Catalog.Page` is now a full list of Objects
Each Object under `Catalog.Page` contains approximately 42 objects of their own, and each of those objects has different values including `Name`

I wish to be able to, once you have called `Cataog.scan(1, 100)`, search for any Objects in any of the Pages that contain a certain string in their name, then to return those objects in JSON format (as in return the actual object; not the string)

This is my current code, all of it works entirely except for `Catalog.search`, which returns '[]' several hundred times

Thank you for any help you can provide, I appreciate it

```
var Catalog = {
    def_scan_page:'http://www.roblox.com/catalog/json?browse.aspx?CatalogContext=1&SortType=0&SortAggregation=3&SortCurrency=0&LegendExpanded=true&Category=Featured&PageNumber=',
    load:function(page) {
        $.get(Catalog.def_scan_page+page).done(function(r) {
            Catalog.Page[page] = r;
            console.log("Loaded page",page);
        });
    },
    scan:function(min, max) {
        max++;
        for (i=min;i<max;i++) {
            Catalog.load(i);
        }
    },
    search:function(string) {
        function getObjects(obj, key, val) {
            var objects = [];
            for (var i in obj) {
                if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;
                if (typeof obj[i] == 'object') {
                    objects = objects.concat(getObjects(obj[i], key, val));
                } else if (i == key && obj[key] == val) {
                    objects.push(obj);
                }
            }
            return objects;
        }
        for (var page in Catalog.Page) {
            for (var item in Catalog.Page[page]) {
                console.log(getObjects(Catalog.Page[page][item], 'Name', string))
            }
        }
    },
    Page:{
    },
}
```

Comment: you have too many returns. you need to define your final collection as an array above getObjects() and push to that array from inside getObjects() instead of using return to get everything (including empties)

Comment: How do I do that though?